# Primeng table with paginator

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I have datatable with paginator.

`<p-table [value]="data" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10">`

When I have no data on the page my datatable is collapsed.
Is it any possibility to set property like [min-rows]?
I have looked in primeng documentation but any results.
I don't want to use scroll.
Have you any idea how to resolve this problem?

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfFrt.png)

EDIT:
@Shai, this setting makes the whole table goes wrong.

When I set fixed height for my table, for example:

.p-datatable-tbody { height: 500px; }

it looks good but td resizes (picture).

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcL0B.png)

Comment: From what I understand, it seems that setting the table height to 100% or `flex-grow: 1` if you're using flexbox on its container will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: @Shai, have you any idea?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my previous comment? Are you using flexbox in the container?

Comment: Yes, as I said this setting makes the whole table goes wrong.

Comment: I am using p-grid. All I want is to avoid stretching of table rows with fixed table height.

Comment: Try using the following style: `.p-datatable-wrapper { height: 600px; }`